# Entity Framework Code First issue to create the database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create the database using EF Code First approach. I have a `DataAccessLayer` and a `DomainLayer` in the following way :

```
namespace DomainLayer
{
   public class Lodging
   {
      public int LodgingId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Owner { get; set; }
      public bool IsResort { get; set; }
      public Destination Destination { get; set; }
   }

   public class Destination
   {
      public int DestinationId { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Country { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

      public List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
   }
}
```

---

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using DomainLayer;

namespace DataAccessLayer
{
   public class BreakAwayContext : DbContext
   {
      public DbSet<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
   }
}
```

And I create a Console application to test the app in the following way :

```
namespace BreakAwayConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          InsertDestination();
       }

       private static void InsertDestination()
       {
          var destination = new Destination
         {
             Country = "Indonesia",
             Description = "EcoTourism at its best in exquisite Bali",
             Name = "Bali"
         };

         using (var context = new BreakAwayContext())
         {
            context.Destinations.Add(destination);
            context.SaveChanges();
         }
       }
     }
}
```

But when I run the app it gave me the following error :

**Exception:**

`An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.`

**Message:**

`The provider did not return a string ProviderManifestToken.`

**InnerException:**

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while a connection to SQL Server is established. Server not found or was not accessible this. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server or Instance Specified)`

I'm have installed in my machine SQL Server 2005 too. But according to book I'm reading :

*Code First used the information it discovered in the Destination and Lodging classes to determine the model and infer the schema of the database that these classes are persisted in. Since we provided no connection string information, it uses its default convention, which is to look in the local SQL Server Express instance (localhost\SQLEXPRESS) for a database matching the fully qualified name of the context class DataAccess.BreakAwayContext. Not finding one, Code First creates the database and then uses the model it discovered by convention to build the tables and columns of the database.*

**EDIT**

My `app.config` file it's in the `BreakAwayConsole` project and have the following lines :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess here that you have the connection string information in the app.config of the datalayer project, but the connection string information is not in the app.config of your console application.

You can just copy and past the connection string information from the datalayer app.config into the console app.config and you should be all set.

Comment: @jrhutch My connection string it' in my console application project, not in the datalayer

Comment: Does the server name in your connection string match the instance name  you're seeing in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: What is the name of the connectionString in the App.config?  It should be BreakAwayContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having dealt with various connection string , I solved my problem with the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="BreakAwayContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=BreakAwayContext; Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I thought you did not  want to edit the app.config - you don't need to if you can ensure you can connect to .\sqlexpress locally

Comment: @ozidom SQLEXPRESS don't come wiht Visual Studio by default??

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to add the connection string information to the app.config file.  I think you're config file should look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection " connectionString="Data Source=YourServerName;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Unless he specifies the name of the connection string in his context, he'll want to name it DefaultConnection, right?

Comment: Why I need to define a connection string manually??  ...Code First creates the database and then uses the model it discovered by convention

Comment: @Vkt0rS. It's going to try to find a server based on convention, but if that fails, and it appears that it is failing, then going explicit is the way to fix it.

Comment: +1 to @Smith.h.Neil Yes, it does need to be DefaultConnection, I always create a default constructor for my dbContext to specify my connection string name. Public MyDbContext() : base("MyDbContext") {//any config}  Updated my answer

Comment: @Vkt0rS. after looking at your question and the quote from the book, I think the problem is that your SQL instance is a default instance (localhost) rather than a localhost\SQLExpress.  Either way I would recommend explicitly defining the connection in the app.config.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem. I as not able to connect to .\SQLEXPRESS. I managed to get it working by reinstalling SQLEXPRESS with a named instance of SQLEXPRESS from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=29062 . I could then connect successfully to .\SQLEXPRESS and then ef codefirst worked without any connection strings in the app.config.